# Найти номер последнего отрицательного элемента в последовательности

Tags: qbasic

Найти номер последнего отрицательного элемента в последовательности. Например, если А={2,4,–3,0,5,–2,5}, результат: 6 (число –2).

Как такое реализовать на QBASIC?

Спасибо огромное

Comment: Бейсик... Школьные годы... Компьютер "Агат"...

Comment: Домашка чтоли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Циклом перебираете весь массив.
проверяете элемент массива если он меньше 0 (отрицательный) запоминаете в переменной его номер.
Когда пройдут все итерации массива у вас в переменной будет номер элемента который последний отрицательный.

а как это будет выглядеть в коде делайте сами за вас решать никто не будет.